# Checkboxes in a table from IActions in ContributionManager

Tags: java, swt, action

I am trying to make a table with check boxes. I am already provided with a ContributionManager. The manager have an IAction added for each check box, so I hope there is some way I can reuse the actions for my table.

I would hope for something like

TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.Selection);

item.setAction(oneAction);

But I cant find anything like that.

Am I working in the right direction or does someone have any tips for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check boxes in tables are nothing to do with actions and contribution managers.

If you use `Table` you can specify `SWT.CHECK` as part of the table style:

```
Table table = new Table(parent, SWT.CHECK | ... other styles);
```

Use the `addSelectionListener` to add a listener for selection events. Check events will have the event `detail` set to `SWT.CHECK`.

Or if you use a JFace viewer you can use `CheckboxTableViewer`. Use the `addCheckStateListener` to listen for check state events.

Comment: I don't know what all the events are doing. I am modifying a program where IActions are provided for a IToolBarManager. I want to move the actions from the toolbar into an table.

Comment: You can't. Tables don't support actions. You would have to use the listeners to work out which row has been checked and call the `run` method of the action.